# c# sockets blocking

Tags: c#, sockets, blocking

Say I have a TcpClient that I accept from a TcpServer in c#, and for some reason it keeps defaulting with blocking off. Is there some other force that can change how the socket blocking is set? Like say is it affected by the remote connection at all?

I know I set blocking to fale a few builds back, but I changed it, and even introduced the TcpClient instead of a straight socket. I haven't specifically changed the blocking back to true, I just commented blocking = false out. Is that something that persists maybe with the endpoint?

I don't know though it just seemed that as I was programming one day my sockets just became unruley without any real change in their code.

```
public void GetAcceptedSocket(TcpClient s)
{
    try
    {
        sock = s;
        IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = s.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        strHost = remoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString();
        intPort = remoteIpEndPoint.Port;
        ipEnd = remoteIpEndPoint;
        sock.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
        boolConnected = true;
        intLastPing = 0;
        LastPingSent = DateTime.Now;
        LastPingRecieved = DateTime.Now;
        handleConnect(strHost, intPort);
        oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run));
        oThread.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        handleError(e, "Connect method: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no answer, I've never duplicated this, and after a few months, and a fresh windows install,  picked the code up, and didn't have the problem anymore. Very weird though, defiantly couldn't find a programmatic reasoning for it happening. Like I said, after a few months it just kinda worked?
They should really have an 'Unawnserable' option :p.

Comment: Hey, I asked a moderator and they told me to vote on my own awnser. So don't downvote me.

Answer (score 2):

> Like say is it affected by the remote
>   connection at all?

Nope.

It would have been better if you show some code where you create `Socket` or `TcpClient` in server side. I cannot find `TcpServer` class in C#. Are you talking about `TcpListener`?
If you are, please make it sure that you `set Socket's Blocking true` if you use `AcceptSocket` to create a new socket. If you call `AcceptTcpClient`, you should not worry about blocking or non-blocking mode as `TcpClient` is always blocking mode.

> The TcpClient class provides simple
>   methods for connecting, sending, and
>   receiving stream data over a network
>   in **synchronous blocking mode**.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx).

Comment: That's great, but was I was saying is that when AcceptTcpClient it was giving me a TcpClient with a socked with the blocking off. That was the concern.

Comment: @kelton25, how do you know the blocking is off?

Comment: Breakpoints, checked the status of the TcpClient.Client.Blocking

Comment: I know, just doesn't seem to make any sense. I even searched my whole solution for the word blocking, incase I shut it off somewhere else...I'll post up a little code.

Comment: Not only does using a breakpoint and viewing the status of blocking say false, it acts like blocking is off. If the read has no data, it passes right over it immediately, and I get wouldblock errors. That's why I went looking in the first place.

Comment: @kelton25 wow. I don't think I can help you any further unless I actually debug client and server. hope someone else can help you!

Comment: Thanks anyhow, was just hoping somone had this issue and had an idea. Kinda strange.

Comment: Oh, and I had blocking specificly enabled above, the problem goes away if I do that. Just if I don't specify blocking, it'll be off.